# confusing error when using minimize of lmfit in python

Tags: python-3.5, lmfit

my code is as following:

```
import numpy as np
from math import *
from scipy.optimize import *
import scipy.optimize as opt
from lmfit import Minimizer, Parameters, report_fit
import lmfit as lf

f = open('data.txt','r')
lines=f.readlines()   

n1=[]
n2=[]
n=[]
h=[]
for x in lines:
    x=x.strip() # remove \n before splitting the line
    n1.append(x.split('\t')[0])
    n2.append(x.split('\t')[1])
    n.append(x.split('\t')[2])
    h.append(x.split('\t')[3])
f.close()

n1 = [float(i) for i in n1]
n2 = [float(i) for i in n2]
n = [float(i) for i in n]
h = [float(i) for i in h]
# convert a list into an array
n1 = np.array(n1)
n2 = np.array(n2)
n = np.array(n)
h = np.array(h)

def fith(params,n1,n2,n,h):
    a1 = params['p1']
    b1 = params['p2']
    a2 = params['p3']
    b2 = params['p4']
    model = (a1 + b1*n) * n1 + (a2 + b2*n) * n2
    return model - h

params = Parameters()
params.add('p1',value=1.0)
params.add('p2',value=1.0)
params.add('p3',value=1.0)
params.add('p4',value=1.0)

out = minimize(fith,params,args=(n1,n2,n,h))

print(out)
```

after run, I got the error as following:

#### #

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\new model\calculate_H_v2.py", line 50, in 
    out = minimize(fith,params,args=(n1,n2,n,h))
  File "E:\softwares\python\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize_minimize.py", line 481, in minimize
    return _minimize_bfgs(fun, x0, args, jac, callback, **options)
  File "E:\softwares\python\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 943, in _minimize_bfgs
    gfk = myfprime(x0)
  File "E:\softwares\python\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 292, in function_wrapper
    return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
  File "E:\softwares\python\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 703, in approx_fprime
    return _approx_fprime_helper(xk, f, epsilon, args=args)
  File "E:\softwares\python\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 637, in _approx_fprime_helper
    f0 = f(*((xk,) + args))
  File "E:\softwares\python\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 292, in function_wrapper
    return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
  File "E:\new model\calculate_H_v2.py", line 35, in fith
    a1 = params['p1']
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

#### #

I could not figure it out why I got this kind of error after read through the questions. Can you help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Jing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the basic problem is that you are using `scipy.optimize.minimize()` instead of `lmfit.minimize()`.  That is, you `import *` from `scipy.optimize`, then you import `Minimizer` from `lmfit`.

That is, using `from lmfit import minimize, Parameters, report_fit`, or use

```
mini = Minimizer(fith,params,args=(n1,n2,n,h))
out = mini.minimize()
```

should make your script use `lmfit.minimize()` which looks to me like it should then work.

This is why `import *` is painful: you have a hard time telling where symbols came from.

As a side comment, you can probably use `numpy.loadtxt()` to simplify the reading of your data to numpy arrays.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advise! It works quite well.